# Select value that does not exist in another column of the same table, MySQL Database Not Exists Clause

Tags: mysql, database, exists

What I'm trying to do here is to select all *contract_id* that does not exist in the *prev_contract_id* column and whereby the end date is earlier than a date.

Here is my database table called **contract**, and the values are in
(*contract id*, *contract type*, *start date*, *end date*, *prev contract id*, *staff id*) columns

```
insert into contract values('co-0000001', 'Monthly', '2014-01-01', '2014-02-01','null', 'staff3');
insert into contract values('co-0000002', 'Yearly', '2013-07-07', '2014-07-06','null', 'staff3');
insert into contract values('co-0000003', 'Monthly', '2014-03-20', '2014-04-19','co-0000001', 'staff4');
insert into contract values('co-0000004', 'Yearly', '2014-02-27', '2015-03-27','null', 'staff4');
insert into contract values('co-0000005', 'Ad-hoc', '2014-02-27', '2015-03-27','null', 'staff4');
insert into contract values('co-0000006', 'Yearly', '2013-02-27', '2014-02-27','null', 'staff4');
```

**Here is my SQL statement**

```
select contract_id from contract 
where not exists(select prev_contract_id from contract where prev_contract_id <> 'null') 
and end_date < '2014-05-05';
```

**The results of each individual select statements**

```
select prev_contract_id from contract where prev_contract_id <> 'null';
```

returns me `co-0000001` contract_id, and

```
select contract_id from contract where end_date < '2014-05-05';
```

returns me `co-0000001`, `co-0000003`, `co-0000006`.
I want to eliminate `co-0000001` from the selection and only return me co-0000003 and co-0000006.

It works when i run them separately, but when i combine them together using the `NOT EXISTS` clause, I was not able to get my results. I do not want to use `IN` as I heard it's more time consuming or inefficient.

Comment: Provide your table structure

Comment: check the column datatype and check by replacing "not exists" with "not in" and check the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `not exists` operator wrong. This operator means that for every row in the outer select statement, the inner select is evaluated, and only if it returns no rows the row from the outer query is returned.

If you examine the inner query you're using:

```
select prev_contract_id from contract where prev_contract_id <> 'null'
```

You will see that it has nothing to do with the outer query. Since there exists rows where `prev_contract_id <> 'null'`, no row from the outer query is ever returned.

What you're missing is an additional condition that ties the inner query with the `contract_id` of the outer one:

```
SELECT contract_id 
FROM   contract a
WHERE  NOT EXISTS(SELECT prev_contract_id 
                  FROM   contract b
                  WHERE  b.prev_contract_id <> 'null' AND
                         b.prev_contract_id = a.contract_id -- The missing relationship
                 ) AND
       end_date < '2014-05-05';
```